# VSTS contribution "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form" not depend on work item type

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating an extension for VSTS which target work item form and render a page on work item form.

But i want to render that tab page on only Test Type work item, but contribution allows on each work item.

Is it possible to depend on work item type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this could not be achieved when targeting `ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form`.

> We **delivered the ability in the admin UI** to configure which types
>   get an extension but we have **no immediate plans to be similar logic
>   in the json manifest**.

The reason also described as below:

> We considered letting the extension author specify this in their JSON
>   manifest but that is too limiting since **users** will soon be able to
>   **create custom work item types** and an extension author would never know what those are.
>
> *[Source Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/issues/16)*

So it't not able to do the limitation as an extension developer, the users could do their customization in the process --work item type-- Layout page.

[image]

They could also do this by export the work item type, details please refer the *Extensibility with the new work item form* part in the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/01/13/new-work-item-form-in-tfs-2017/).

Besides, since you are doing the work item form customization, take a look at this tutorial [**Creating work item form extensions in Visual Studio Team Services**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/13/creating-work-item-form-extensions-in-visual-studio-team-services/) which maybe helpful to you.

Comment: Hi PatrickLu, this is fine i saw the link above in which observer can hide the page, i tried, but cannot find any workaround how?, can you post a snippet?

Comment: @NitinParashar  Sorry, not sure if I totally got your point, seems you want to use observer hide the entire extension hub/page in work item form. It's not possible. The Observer  is initialized as **a hidden iframe** in the form. It’s not visible to the user but it can still interact with the form using the services provided. It used to listen events or perform actions on work item form. The details sample please take a look at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension#listen-for-events